# NodeJS Socket.IO : indexOf not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, indexof, socket.io

I'm trying to understand why my indexOf is not working ! Actually, everytime a user load a page of the website, the server receive the variable "data" who is containing one (just for the moment) value : the name of the user.

client.js :

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
    url: "ajax.php",
    data: {
        ajaxRequest: "userInfos"
    },
    success: function(data){
        var data = JSON.parse(data);
        var userInfos = {
            name: data.username,
        }
        socket.emit('pong',JSON.stringify(userInfos));
    }
});
```

server.js :

```
client.on('pong',function(data){
        var data = JSON.parse(data);
        if(data.name != null) { // On s'assure qu'il est connecté
            /** VARIABLES SESSION **/
            client.set("name",data.name);
            client.set("id",client.id);
            /** VARIABLES SESSION **/
            if(connected.indexOf(data.name) == -1){ // Si il n'est pas dans le tableau
                var usersInfos = {
                    name: data.name,
                    id: client.id
                };

                io.sockets.emit('pong',JSON.stringify(usersInfos));
                connected.push(JSON.stringify(usersInfos)); // On remet son pseudo
                console.log("[PONG] "+data.name+" ("+client.id+") est connecté");
            }
        }
    });
```

So usersInfos will be completed ONLY if the user isn't already existing in the object but actually, isn't working... He push the user after every page loading or refresh...

Here is how connected and usersInfos are declared :

```
var connected = [];
var usersInfos = {};
```

Please help me, I will kill someone !

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> connected.push(JSON.stringify(usersInfos))
> …
> connected.indexOf(data.name) == -1
> ```

If you're pushing JSON strings on the `connected` array, you won't be able to find the sole `.name` in there. Hope to have saved a live :-)

Comment: Sorry for the delay ! I didn't understood... Actually data is parsed "var data = JSON.parse(data)" so at the "connected.indexOf(data.name)"  "connected" is parsed and "data" too !

Comment: Yes, `data` is a parsed object, but `JSON.stringify(usersInfos)` obviously is not.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by writing a multidimensional object function !

Here is the function :

```
/** 
 * Création d'un tableau d'objets multidimensionnel
 */
function mdimAdd(arrayName,values) {
    // On vérifie si l'array est déjà un objet ou non.
    if(typeof(arrayName) == "object") {
        arrayName = JSON.stringify(arrayName); // Si oui, on la transforme en string
    } 

    arrayName = arrayName.slice(0,-1); // On supprime le dernier caractère
    if(S(arrayName).endsWith("}")) {
        arrayName = arrayName+",";
    }

    arrayName = arrayName+""+values; // On rajoute les valeures 
    arrayName = arrayName+"}"; // On ferme l'objet

    return JSON.parse(arrayName); // On retourne le tableau sous forme d'objet JSON
}
```

And here is the line to create the multidimensional object :

```
usersInfos = mdimAdd(usersInfos,'"'+data.name+'": {"name": "'+data.name+'","id": "'+client.id+'"}');
```

Then now I do that :

```
client.on('pong',function(data){
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        if(data.name != null) { // On s'assure qu'il est connecté
            /** VARIABLES SESSION **/
            client.set("name",data.name);
            client.set("id",client.id);
            /** VARIABLES SESSION **/

            if(!usersInfos[data.name]){ // Si il n'est pas dans le tableau
                usersInfos = mdimAdd(usersInfos,'"'+data.name+'": {"name": "'+data.name+'","id": "'+client.id+'"}');
                console.log("[PONG] "+data.name+" ("+client.id+") est connecté");
            }
        }
    });
```